# JMESPath: conditional string replacement

Tags: jmespath

I'm integrating with a webhook that has a simple JSON object payload. I want to use a JMESPath expression to map certain values in the provided JSON object payload to valid values in my data schema.

So, for example, if the submitted data is `{"contact": "Text message"}` or `{"contact": "Phone call"}`, I want to get out of the JMESPath expression `"phone"`, and if `"contact"` is not one of those two values, I want to get out of the JMESPath expression `"email"`.

Any suggestions on how to do such conditional string replacement at the top level of the provided object?

Answer (score 0):

in theory, you can build JMESPath expression which will return `true` if the text is what you expect and `false` for other cases.

Here is an example of JMESPath expression that uses `contains` function and `OR` expression:
`[contact.contains(@,'Text message')||contact.contains(@,'Phone call')]`

To break down things let's see how it works in Python console:

```
>>> text=[{"contact": "other"}]
>>> text
[{'contact': 'other'}]
>>> jmespath.search("[*][contact.contains(@,'Text message')||contact.contains(@,'Phone call')]", text)
[[False]]
>>> text=[{"contact": "Text message"}]
>>> text
[{'contact': 'Text message'}]
>>> jmespath.search("[*][contact.contains(@,'Text message')||contact.contains(@,'Phone call')]", text)
[[True]]
>>> text=[{"contact": "Phone call"}]
>>> text
[{'contact': 'Phone call'}]
>>> jmespath.search("[*][contact.contains(@,'Text message')||contact.contains(@,'Phone call')]", text)
[[True]]
```

I hope this helps you a bit :)

If you want to find out more about JMESPath with examples and recommended tools take a look at [here](https://www.doaws.pl/blog/2021-12-05-how-to-master-aws-cli-in-15-minutes/how-to-master-aws-cli-in-15-minutes).